# How to run a library in docker - confusion

Tags: macos, docker, terminal, installation, cntk

I am trying to use [microsoft's cntk library](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK) on a mac; for this purpose I am using [Docker](https://www.docker.com/). I am not an expert in all this, though, so I am having a hard time figuring out how to make it work.

From my understanding, Docker provides a way to run an app in a virtualized environment, without having to virtualize the entire operating system. So you download (or create) images, and you run them in "containers".

Alright, so I have followed the [required steps](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTk/wiki/CNTK-Docker-Containers#using-docker-container-to-run-cntk-jupyter-notebook-tutorials) to make the cntk library work on Docker; and if I list the images, I find

```
$: docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
microsoft/cntk      latest              c2c192036e19        7 days ago          5.92 GB
ubuntu              14.04               7c09e61e9035        5 weeks ago         188 MB
hello-world         latest              48b5124b2768        2 months ago        1.84 kB
```

At this point I want to run of the tutorials that are in the cntk repository. I have downloaded the master branch of the cntk repository on my desktop and try to run one of the examples in the "Tutorial" folder, but I get the following error:

```
terminal~ username$  docker run -w /Users/username/Desktop/CNTK-master/Tutorials microsoft/cntk configFile=lr_bs.cntk
container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"configFile=lr_bs.cntk\": executable file not found in $PATH"
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"configFile=lr_bs.cntk\": executable file not found in $PATH".
ERRO[0001] error getting events from daemon: net/http: request canceled 
terminal~ username$
```

Essentially I call docker run with the -w flag to inform him of where the files are, but it does not work. I tried searching online but it's not clear to me how to solve the issue. Should I create a new image? Should I call the docker run command with different parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-w` flag sets the working directory, which is just the default directory *inside the container*. Your directory is on the *host*, so it won't work here. Instead you need to use volumes to mount your directory on the host into the container. The final paragraph in the document you link has an example:

```
$ docker run --name cntk_container1 -ti -v /project1/data:/data -v /project1/config:/config cntk bash
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Thanks, this is indeed what I needed :)